# How to get Data of Only and Only Last Date of Partition in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need a measure that get me only last Data of last Date in partition. 
All resources on the Internet use code block below to handle this challenge :

```
  with member [Measures.LastData]
  (
      [Measures].[Measure Name]
     ,
      Tail(filter([Dim Date Time].[Int Date].children,not IsEmpty( 
      [Measures].
  [Measure Name])))
  ).item(0)
```

But I Don't need this code. This code get us only last non empty of each Data of date.

if we inject some dimension member to it and if we have no Data for the last Date, then Date-1 have been see , if not exist, Date -2 and ...

For example we have

date                name                 price

2017-01-01          mahdi                20000

2017-01-01          ali                  10000

2017-01-02          mahdi                30000

2017-01-02          Mohammad             50000

Then I only want to have 2017-01-02 - mahdi and mohammad not ali in 2017-01-01

Comment: Could you please add the code which returns the output below?

Comment: with member measures.GetMeLastNonEmptyValue as
(
       CASE WHEN [IsOtherDimensionNotuse] then
       (
            (
         [Measures].[Price]
         ,
         Tail(filter([DimDateTime].[Int Date].children,not isempty( [Measures].[Price])))
             ).item(0)
        )
        else
            measures.[AnotherMeasureNotImportant]
        end
)

This measure first see if dimension member not injected to query get last non empty of that example
[IsOtherDimensionNotuse] is another measure that is not important

Comment: Tail(NonEmpty([Dim Date Time].[Int Date].Members,[Measures].[Measure Name]) * [Name].[Name].[Name].Members * ...

Comment: Hey thanks. but when you use tail, you want to say Last non empty not last value. your measure is not my answer

Comment: Do you need last record of what? You pointed both mahdi and mohammad.

Comment: Last record of last date. In my example last date is 2 jun 2017 but your answer get me ali in 1 jun

Comment: Are you sure? What Tail(NonEmpty([Dim Date Time].[Int Date].Members,[Measures].[Measure Name]).UniqueName will return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my quest

```
    CREATE HIDDEN SET CURRENTCUBE.[ProcessedDate] AS 
    (       
    FILTER
    (
        [DimWsDateTime].[Int Date].[Int Date].Members,
        (InStr(1, [DimWsDateTime].[Int Date].CurrentMember.NAME, 

            TAIL(
                    NONEMPTY(
                        [DimWsDateTime].[Int Date].[Int Date]
                        ,
                        [Measures].[Faultvalue]
                    )
                    ,1
                ).Item(0).MemberValue
    ) <> 0) 
    )); 



    WITH MEMBER  [measures].[IsOtherDimensionNotuse_] as
        Count(existing [DimWsDateTime].[Int Date].[Int Date].Members) = Count([DimWsDateTime].[Int Date].[Int Date].Members)

        MEMBER [measures].[SuccessRatioToAll_] as 
        (([Measures].[RecordCount] - [Measures].[Is Fault Activity])/[Measures].[RecordCount])

        MEMBER [measures].[LastvalueSuccessRatioToAll] as 
        (
            CASE WHEN [IsOtherDimensionNotuse_] then
               (
                    (
                        [Measures].[SuccessRatioToAll_]
                        ,
                        [ProcessedDate]
                     ).item(0)
                )
                else
                    measures.[SuccessRatioToAll_]
            end
        )
    select [measures].[LastvalueSuccessRatioToAll] on 0 from [MohebWebSrviceDetails]
```